# Bad temper vs. A bad temper

Tags: expressions

I would like others to explain this to me.

-He has bad temper.
-He has a bad temper.

Are both correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's idiomatic to say that someone has **a** temper (or a bad temper), meaning that the person concerned is easily aroused.

You can't say that someone has temper. It's not idiomatic. Although you can say that someone is bad-tempered (or even-tempered or good-tempered).

As Michael Harvey points out in his example, you can also talk about temper in general without using an article. **Bad temper is common these days** and **his unruly behavior arises from bad temper**. You can also talk about **his bad temper** and **her good temper** without the article.

But somebody always has **a** temper.

Comment: Also, steel has **temper** from its [production process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempering_(metallurgy)). It's a general attribute.

Answer (score -1):

A bad temper is a noun so you need the determiner "a". The second one is correct.

> He has a bad temper.

Your first example is incorrect and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Bad temper can be non- countable; e.g. his rudeness is often caused by bad temper.